# AWS Dynamo DB Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am trying to query Dynamo DB using lambda below is the code.

```
exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
region: "us-west-1"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
console.log("Querying ");
var params = {
TableName : "BankApp",
KeyConditionExpression: "#yr = :Value",
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
"#yr": "Test"
},
ExpressionAttributeNames : {
":Value" : {"S" : "TEST" }
 }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
} else {
    console.log("Query succeeded.");
    data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(" -", item.Account_NUM + ": " + item.ACCOUNT_BAL);
    });
}
});
}
```

But i am getting Error Saying :
Unable to query. Error: {
  "message": "ExpressionAttributeNames contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: \":Value\"",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2018-07-17T15:20:40.308Z",

Comment: It looks like the contents of `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` need to be swapped.

Comment: Also if you are using the DocumentClient you don't need to do `":Value" : {"S" : "TEST" }` just use `":Value": "TEST"`

Comment: You have to change the order of your syntaxes like below,
`var params = {
    TableName: 'BankApp',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#yr = :value', 
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { 
        '#yr': 'test'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
      ':value': '{"S": "TEST"}'
    }
};`

Comment: I tried but getting  "message": "Requested resource not found", after swap also i tried the code sent from sameera still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, I was using wrong region.